# MapStruct: mapping from object with a list of complex object

Tags: spring, mapstruct

Supposing I have the following classes:

```
public class A {
private String id;
private List<B> related;
}

public class B {
private String id;
private String name;
}

public class ADTO {
private String id;
private List<BDTO> relations;
}

public class BDTO {
private String identificator;
private String relatedName;
}
```

How can I create a mapper that given an A object type returns me an ADTO object with all the information? I have to create two different mappers? Can it be done in only one mapper? I think it would be something like the following, but I don't know how to map the atributtes from the list:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mappings({ @Mapping(source = "related", target = "relations") })
    ADTO mapperA(A obj);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (not tested but should work properly)

when you mapping lists you should make a map for both the class element and the list to map all the elements of the list)

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mappings({ @Mapping(source = "related", target = "relations") })
    ADTO mapperA(A obj);

    @Mappings(
      { @Mapping(source = "id", target = "identificator") },
      { @Mapping(source = "name", target = "relatedName") })
    BDTO bDTOMapping(B b);

    List<BDTO> bDTOListMapping(List<B> bList);
}
```